# Change part of an string for a colored in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net

I have a RichTextBox with a full string. I need to color all words corresponding to names, e.g. Marta, Oscar and Ricardo. How can I achieve this?

This is the code I have so far. It replaces the string and put it into a RichTextBox:

```
private void btnFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query_orig = rtxtQuery.Text;
    string qry_reemp_oscar = query_orig.Replace("oscar", "OSCAR");
    string qry_reemp_marta= qry_reemp_coma.Replace("marta", "MARTA");
    string qry_reemp_final = qry_reemp_select.Replace(
        " ricardo ", System.Environment.NewLine + " RICARDO ");
    rtxtQryLinea.Text = qry_reemp_final;
}
```

Comment: Would you please share what you have tried so far and what exactly you struggle with?

Comment: updated @Quality Catalyst

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
int pos = rtb.TextLength;
rtb.AppendText(txt);
rtb.Select(pos, txt.Length);
rtb.SelectionColor = col;
rtb.Select();
```

Comment: Cover your code-snippet with some explanations and details. At this moment your answer is a low-quality answer and more a comment-like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string query_orig = rtxtQuery.Text;
query_orig = query_orig.Replace("oscar", "OSCAR");
query_orig = query_orig.Replace("marta", "MARTA");
query_orig = query_orig.Replace("ricardo ", "RICARDO ");
 rtxtQryLinea.Text = query_orig;

rtxtQryLinea.Select(query_orig.IndexOf("OSCAR"), "OSCAR".Length);
rtxtQryLinea.SelectionColor = Color.Aqua;

rtxtQryLinea.Select(query_orig.IndexOf("MARTA"), "MARTA".Length);
rtxtQryLinea.SelectionColor = Color.Coral;

rtxtQryLinea.Select(query_orig.IndexOf("RICARDO"), "RICARDO".Length);
rtxtQryLinea.SelectionColor = Color.OrangeRed;
```

Comment: I tried, it works nicely, but... it only colors the first time it finds a 'name' (like 'OSCAR') but not additional parts where 'OSCAR' is also found. Any suggestion?